# Is this spreading a lie considered lying?

Tags: ethics, truth, information, immortality, introduction-to-philosophy

So if person A is fed false information by person B, and person A goes on to tell this information to person C in the best way possible in the exact way they heard it are they lying? Person A would be telling the truth if the information was correct but unbeknownst to them it is incorrect information.

**Is person A lying to person C?**

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question directly related to the English language as the same situation could arise in any language. The real question is whether passing on false information in any circumstances constitutes a lie or whether an intent to deceive is required?

Comment: So do you suggest I visit another site or do you have an answer?

Comment: Check Fillmore's ["Verbs of Judging"](https://ur.booksc.me/book/35802761/715de9). The concepts of "truth" and "lie" are a big deal in philosophy. The Cretan puzzles are a good example.

Comment: @KillingTime Lying requires *mens rea*. Without intent to deceive there can be no lie, but that doesn't make it true! Even telling the truth can be done with the intention to deceive, but that doesn't make it a lie.

Comment: This question must be answered 'indeterminate' unless pragmatics of normal usage are considered, when according to  every dictionary I've checked in the intention to deceive is a necessary element of lying. What does _your_ research show? There are probably stipulative definitions in logic etc meaning an unqualified 'utter etc something not factually accurate', but before using these non-standard-default usages one would have to be sure of the domain default/define terms, or be violating the Gricean maxim of clarity.

Comment: Intent to deceive is not observable, and therefore exists only in the mind. So whether it's a lie is not a linguistic question, but a philosophical one.

Comment: @tchrist Blake: "*A truth that's told with bad intent beats all the lies you can invent.*"

Comment: "Tooth fairies are real" - lying "I was told that tooth fairies are real" - not lying Simple distinction between how the information is relayed

Comment: By the way you word the question the answer is a resounding NO IT IS NOT A LIE. By definition a LIE is the deliberate omission of details that are use to deceive.That is to say, one must know they are omitting "relevant information" that if given would change the result of the situation (like a yes answer to a no answer). For example a child misbehaving will ask for cookies but get told no. If the child asks a new person unaware the child misbehaved the answer can be different from NO. The child will omit he misbehaved to get a YES answer. If you repeat a false claim it is just a false claim.

Comment: @Logikal Perhaps this is why 'gossip' is universally discouraged? It basically means that we knowingly pass on only partial information when we know we don't have the whole story. Like walking on thin ice: only a matter of time before something will go wrong.

Comment: @ScottRowe we may pass on partial information but we ought to admit it is only partial.  When we state partial but try to make it seem like more than that we are approaching deception.  When I omit information because it will benefit me that is manipulation & deception.

Comment: @Logikal Yes, my thought is that gossip is kind of like possibly counterfeit money: people pass it on and don't want to be caught holding it because they are dealing with an unreliable "social economy". They have to 'trade' to get their needs met living in the social environment, and the false info is someone else's problem. Lies then would simply be counterfeiting. Any traction with this analogy?

Comment: @Scott rowers, I want to be clear: any fLse statement is NOT a lie. A lie has to involve intent to decieve not ignorance to the fact. So if you intentionally pass me fake money knowing it is fake that is intentional deception. Now I pass the fake money to someone else where I do not know the money is fake Ithen i am not spreading a LIE. The money happens to be fake but i am not using it to deceive i just don't know it is fake. My ignorance doesn't spread a Lie. Intent is how moral judgments are analyzed. Objectively you know or you don't know.

Comment: @Logikal What if you don't know one way or the other but because of lots of counterfeit money in your neighborhood you don't want to be left holding the bag so you spend it as fast as you can? I don't know how long the milk in the fridge will stay good (if it even is now) so I aim to use it sooner rather than later. Same for social capital?

Comment: @Scott rowers, if you don't know then there is no deception on your part. Any wrong acts about fake money done by you would be wrong but out of your ignorance alone. You still may be held liable to some degree but not 100 percent. Still there is no lie on your part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As some of the comments allude to, a [lie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie) is generally considered a communication with an intent to deceive. WP uses this definition:

> A lie is an assertion that is believed to be false, typically used with the purpose of deceiving someone.

As such, if person B is relaying with good faith a communication from person A, they are not lying because they most likely have themselves been deceived, although it is arguable that person B has ethical obligations to verify the communication from person A. For instance, if person B is a newspaper reporter and mindlessly passes on a claim, then they may very well be in violation of [journalistic ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journalism_ethics_and_standards). This notion of the difference between those who intentionally and unintentionally pass false information is covered by a distinction between [misinformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misinformation) and [disinformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinformation). Note that if person B is doing a favor for person A, then B's noble intentions may not absolve A from ethical responsibilities. A classic proverb is ["The road to hell is paved with good intentions."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_road_to_hell_is_paved_with_good_intentions) Thus, a [ethical consequentialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentialism) will ultimately judge person B and their ethics by the outcome of spreading misinformation.

Comment: If someone passes on a lie that they should have verified, they can be said to have [reckless disregard for the truth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/reckless%20disregard%20of%20the%20truth), which isn't the same as lying, but may have less legal protection than something which you sincerely and reasonably believe to be true.

Comment: I know some people who call it 'lying' when one hides a truth that they know. It seems a stretch to me, but I don't know of a one word name for it otherwise.

Comment: @ScottRowe Lie by omission as opposed to lie by comission.

Comment: Ok. I know the distinction of omission and commission applies to some things. I just always thought of 'lying' as an active verb, so simply remaining quiet doesn't feel like the same sort of action. If someone watched violence, would that be carrying out violence? "... Good men to do nothing" and all, it makes me feel personally responsible for every problem in the world. "*If you're not part of the solution, you're part of the precipitate.*"

Comment: @ScottRowe Inaction in the face of an act of violence is negligence at best and complicity at worst. Both are crimes.

Comment: This is why I don't watch the News. I am guilty in billions of violent acts and murders. Well, everyone knows now.

Comment: @ScottRowe Yes you are. Buber calls it existential guilt.

Comment: @ScottRowe There are lies far worse than commission or omission. When a wrong picture is conveyed without any active (propositional) statement. In Shakespeare's Othello, Iago incites Othello to suspect and ultimately murder his innocent wife Desdemona. Who murders? Othello? Or Iago? There is a similar Agathe Christie novel where the murderer by intent programs insidiously the murderer by act. (which novel eludes me ATM)

Comment: Likewise Hollywood. The minor lie is that there is a veteran called Rambo, a detective called James Bond, Reacher, Miyagi... The major is the amount of punishment they can take and keep fighting. And we complain of gun violence after grossly misleading our impressionable kids about the possibilities and limitations of the human body.

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up "Lies to Children" takes on a very grim interpretation, there. I usually didn't like such movies and TV shows, having gotten enough when I was 6 and the Vietnam War was on the News at dinnertime. Then Cambodia, and on and on. Not sure how to tie that back to lying, but...

Comment: Hypothetically, person A is telling people that person B was seen creeping around outside the house just before the child got murdered.  Person B was investigated by the police and found to have been in a different country and couldn't have committed the murder.  You know both of these things but continue to pass on "Person A told me they saw person B creeping around just before the child got murdered" to anyone you come in contact with.  In that case is a lie of omission no big deal?

Comment: Dunno how you understand "lies to children" @ScottRowe.... See https://youtu.be/17j5QzF3kqE Any lies you detect?? According to the norms I detect here -- there're none

Comment: @EricNolan These things are usually judged by their intent and consequences. Passing on this lie will impact B's reputation among people who are not aware that he has been exonerated (or don't fully trust the investigators), so it's considered wrong.

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up You could always post an identification request on Literature Stack Exchange to locate the book :)

Comment: @ScottRowe This seems to have been produced *just as* I was writing the above comments  https://youtu.be/Ebg2YnBj9II

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up Ok. Hard stop... Maybe. Maybe... *because* I saw the Vietnam War on TV at dinnertime every evening when I was 6, followed by Cambodia, etc... Maybe, I learned about actual violence and death at an early age and never had the slightest interest in videogames, sports, violent movies and shows, shooting guns? Of course I *know how* to use a rifle and a shotgun, I'm actually pretty good at it for being inexperienced, but no interest and I don't own any. **We've been doing it all wrong!** Teach children this stuff right away! Kill the mystery! Make them clean their own fish! Well.

Comment: @Rusi-packing-up ok, I just watched the model video. I guess I was 'hardened' against attacks by advertising when I was young also. Speaking as an adult male though, I find a wide range of body styles, sizes, ages and coloration appealing. Hard to explain to my wife... She thought it seemed disloyal at first. No, it's like, I can say what a cool car without wanting to drive it, what a lovely oak tree without having to dig it up. It's a big world. Contentment goes a long way to enjoying the parts one cannot acquire. Do we teach children this?